# C# multithreading with Monitor hangs

Tags: .net, multithreading, deadlock, monitor

I was reading for MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which has some examples for managing threads with `Monitor` class. But occasionally running example on VS2012 in debug mode wasn't doing anything. I assume that threads were blocking each other in some kind of deadlock. Can someone please explain, what is causing this behaviour?

Copying code to this post:

```
 using System;
 using System.Threading;
 using System.Collections;

 namespace MonitorCS1
 {
    class MonitorSample
    {
        const int MAX_LOOP_TIME = 1000;
        Queue   m_smplQueue;

        public MonitorSample()
        {
            m_smplQueue = new Queue(); 
        }
        public void FirstThread()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            lock(m_smplQueue)
            {
                while(counter < MAX_LOOP_TIME)
                {
                    //Wait, if the queue is busy.
                    Monitor.Wait(m_smplQueue);
                    //Push one element.
                    m_smplQueue.Enqueue(counter);
                    //Release the waiting thread.
                    Monitor.Pulse(m_smplQueue); 

                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        public void SecondThread()
        {
            lock(m_smplQueue)
            {
                //Release the waiting thread.
                Monitor.Pulse(m_smplQueue);
                //Wait in the loop, while the queue is busy.
                //Exit on the time-out when the first thread stops. 
                while(Monitor.Wait(m_smplQueue,1000))
                {
                    //Pop the first element.
                    int counter = (int)m_smplQueue.Dequeue();
                    //Print the first element.
                    Console.WriteLine(counter.ToString());
                    //Release the waiting thread.
                    Monitor.Pulse(m_smplQueue);
                }
            }
        }
        //Return the number of queue elements.
        public int GetQueueCount()
        {
            return m_smplQueue.Count;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create the MonitorSample object.
            MonitorSample test = new MonitorSample();           
            //Create the first thread.
            Thread tFirst = new Thread(new ThreadStart(test.FirstThread));
            //Create the second thread.
            Thread tSecond = new Thread(new ThreadStart(test.SecondThread));
            //Start threads.
            tFirst.Start();
            tSecond.Start();
            //wait to the end of the two threads
            tFirst.Join();
            tSecond.Join();         
            //Print the number of queue elements.
            Console.WriteLine("Queue Count = " + test.GetQueueCount().ToString());
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Where are the threads paused when you pause the debugger?

Comment: Sometimes console was empty even without any debugging, but running in debug mode the last point that debugger was stepping was closing bracket of lock statetement in second thread body.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Monitor.Wait on the same object as you have in your lock. That's the main problem. Its worth mentioning that both Lock and Monitor.Wait are the same thing under the hood - so you are double locking :). Lock is just a nice keyword that the compiler turns into a monitor.

Coming from a high transaction background, its also best to have a private singleton object to lock against. This is good because its reference in memory wont change - where with non static classes, it could possibly.

Its also worth mentioning that having the 2 threads start in the right order as you have done it in code may not result in them starting in the right order.

Here is an example of your code written with the above suggestions (using just the lock keyword):

```
class LockSample
  {
    const int MAX_LOOP_TIME = 50000;
    private static object queueLocker = new object();
    Queue m_smplQueue;

    public LockSample()
    {
      m_smplQueue = new Queue();
    }
    public void FirstThread()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("In thread 1");
      int counter = 0;
      lock (queueLocker)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Adding to queue");
        while (counter < MAX_LOOP_TIME)
        { //Push one element.
          m_smplQueue.Enqueue(++counter);
        }
      }
    }

    public void SecondThread()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("In thread 2");
      lock (queueLocker)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Removing items from the queue");
        while (m_smplQueue.Count > 0)
        {
          //Pop the first element.
          int counter = (int)m_smplQueue.Dequeue();
          //Print the first element.
          Console.Write("\r{0}", counter.ToString());
        }
      }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      //Create the MonitorSample object.
      LockSample test = new LockSample();
      //Create the first thread.
      Thread tFirst = new Thread(new ThreadStart(test.FirstThread));
      //Create the second thread.
      Thread tSecond = new Thread(new ThreadStart(test.SecondThread));
      //Start threads.
      tFirst.Start();
      Thread.Sleep(100);
      tSecond.Start();
      //wait to the end of the two threads

      Console.WriteLine("Waiting for the thread 1");
      tFirst.Join();
      Console.WriteLine("Waiting for the thread 2");
      tSecond.Join();

      Console.WriteLine("\r\nfinished!");
      Console.Read();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I'll check it later and mark your answer. So does it mean that example on MSDN article wasn't created in proper way?

Comment: This piece of code will not wait for the first thread to populate items to the queue. If the timing goes wrong (which cannot be used in production anyway) items will be left in the queue.